# Want to run an exe file which is on my windows server by php site

Tags: php, linux, windows, fopen

I have an unusual problem I want to open an `exe` file which is on my windows server with a php site. I know that I can do it with `fopen` function of php but the problem is that I can not run a php site on windows server and I can not execute any exe file from linux server.

What should I do, do you guys have any idea please let me know.
I can host the site on linux server and put the exe file on windows but in that case the fopen will not work i guess. !!!

Comment: You cannot do it with `fopen` , since that only opens the file, and does not run it. If you aren't allowed to run PHP on the windows machine I doubt you could be allowed to run the file remotely in any other way.

Comment: Pick a function from [System program execution](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. This allows you to execute an external program from a PHP script.

```
echo exec('C:/Path/To/file.exe');
```

You can also try the [COM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) library:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("notepad.exe", 7, false);
```

Comment: dear sir, can i put the exe file in my public_html folder and then use this command ?

Comment: If your exe is a standalone program I guess you can move it, but that will also make your exe public. Otherwise you can just point to the correct location in the system

Comment: and how to run the exec function which a click on a button ?

Comment: This example is when you run the site on the Windows server.